# VBA Excel formatting numbers to strings

Tags: string, excel, vba, formatting

In sheet 1 the value is `45` so I want in sheet RESULTADO the format like this: `0045`

```
Worksheets("RESULTADO").Range("B" & row_counter) = Format(Worksheets(1).Range("B" & row_counter).Value, "0000")
```

Why this doesn't work?

I've tried also this, but neither it works:

```
Worksheets("RESULTADO").Range("B" & row_counter) = CStr(Format(Worksheets(1).Range("B" & row_counter).Value, "0000"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in two(2) ways:

1. Set the number format first

   ```
   With Worksheets("RESULTADO").Range("B" & row_counter)
       .NumberFormat = "@"
       .Value = Format(Worksheets(1).Range("B" & row_counter).Value, "0000")
   End With
   ```
2. Use `'` apostrophe

   ```
   Worksheets("RESULTADO").Range("B" & row_counter) = "'" & _
       Format(Worksheets(1).Range("B" & row_counter).Value, "0000")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't work because in the first case you're trying to format a number n to 00n wich always return n, in the second case, you do exactly the same then you transtype the result to a string. 
You have to convert n to a string first. So in your case :

```
Worksheets("RESULTADO").Range("B" & row_counter) = Format(CStr(Worksheets(1).Range("B" & row_counter).Value), "0000")
```